# Testbench For Entitiy with package - VHDL

Tags: package, vhdl

I have problems in creating a testbench for my test module that used package.
The package just contains a block of array which is accessed in different process.

```
-------------------- Package ---------------------
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
package my_array_pkg is
 type my_array is array ( 0 to 9) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
 end my_array_pkg;
```

And the top entity.

```
----------------- TOP ENTITY -------------------------
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use work.my_array_pkg.all;
    use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity pkt_top is
Port ( sys_clk  : IN STD_LOGIC;
        RESET : IN STD_LOGIC;
        AN_EN   : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
        Seg_Cathodes    : out Std_logic_Vector(6 downto 0)
);      
end pkt_top;

architecture Behavioral of pkt_top is

SIGNAL CLK1HZ, CLK256HZ : STD_LOGIC;
signal my_digit : my_array;

COMPONENT Clock_1Hz is
    Port ( Sys_clk  : in  STD_LOGIC;
                Reset       : in std_logic;
                C_256Hz : out std_logic;
                C_1Hz       : out std_logic
                );
end COMPONENT;

COMPONENT Array_Count is
Port ( C_1Hz    : in std_logic;
        reset   : in std_logic;
        digit   : out my_array
        );
end COMPONENT;

COMPONENT Display_Driver is
Port ( Reset            : in std_logic;
        c256Hz          : in std_logic;
        C_1Hz           : in std_logic;
        digit_in        : in my_array;
        Seg_Cathodes    : out Std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
        An_En           : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
end COMPONENT;

begin

C1 : Clock_1Hz -- Gives two clock divisions.
    PORT MAP ( SYS_CLK, RESET,CLK256HZ,  CLK1HZ);

C2 : Array_Count -- Initialize array with some numbers on every 1Hz edge
    PORT MAP ( CLK1HZ, RESET, my_digit);

C3 : Display_Driver -- Dispaly the numbers on seven segments with 256Hz switching time between segments.
    PORT MAP (RESET , CLK256HZ, CLK1HZ, my_digit, SEG_CATHODES, AN_EN);

end Behavioral;
```

---

The code is synthesizable and works on BASYS2 board, However I cannot simulate it via a testbench.

```
--------------------My TestBench -------------------------
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use work.my_array_pkg.all;

ENTITY pkg_tb IS
END pkg_tb;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF pkg_tb IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT pkt_top
    PORT(
         sys_clk : IN  std_logic;
         RESET : IN  std_logic;
         AN_EN : OUT  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         array_test : INOUT  my_array;
         Seg_Cathodes : OUT  std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal sys_clk : std_logic := '0';
   signal RESET : std_logic := '0';
    signal my_digit : my_array;

    --Outputs
   signal AN_EN : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
   signal Seg_Cathodes : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);

   -- Clock period definitions
   constant sys_clk_period : time := 20 ns;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: pkt_top PORT MAP (
          sys_clk => sys_clk,
          RESET => RESET,
          AN_EN => AN_EN,
          array_test => my_digit,
          Seg_Cathodes => Seg_Cathodes
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   sys_clk_process :process
   begin
        sys_clk <= '0';
        wait for sys_clk_period/2;
        sys_clk <= '1';
        wait for sys_clk_period/2;
   end process;


   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
        reset <= '1';
      wait for 100 ns;
        reset <= '0';

      -- insert stimulus here 

      wait;
   end process;

END;
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

When simulate the ISIM gives an error about the 'array_test' not being availabe in the Top entity, and if this is removed the simulation remains blank.

Any Help about the testbench please.

Comment: You need another process in the testbench that actually performs some tests...

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see a port named "array_test"in the description of the entity pkt_top. You must declare it an an output port in pkt_top.

Comment: I didn't realized that it is required to declare the package signal as INOUT in my top entity as well. Thanks , it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to avoid errors in testbench is to delete the .vhd file of testbench and create a new one for the entity you want to simulate.

In addition to, every time you edit the port of your top entity, you can delete the old and create a new testbench or edit the component of the same entity in your testbench.